# The density of the primitive Pythagorean triples.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The formula of Pythagorean triples is $(a^2+b^2)^2=(2ab)^2+(a^2-b^2)^2$ and a list can be build up with $a^2+b^2$ monotonically increasing. The Pythagorean triples should be primitive here which means $\gcd(a,b)=1$.

The list is $5^2=4^2+3^2$,  $13^2=12^2+5^2$,  $17^2=15^2+8^2$, … and so on.

Be $\#(n)$ the number of primitive Pythagorean triples with $n:=a^2+b^2$.

If $\#(n)$ has several values, e.g. $\#(85)\in\{13;14\}$, than choose the minimum, here $\#(85)=13$. To get $\#(n)$ one counts in the list all triples with $a^2+b^2\leq n$.

How can be proofed $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{\#(n)}=2\pi$$ ? 
It was proofed by Derrick Norman Lehmer, but I cannot find his proof.

Comment: why are you saying that $\#(85) = 13$ ?

Comment: @iqcd : Thanks for the good hint! - How can one mark the question as duplicate ?

Comment: @iqcd : O.k., thank you! :-)